# Solr port disable when connecting to remote server through local machine

Tags: solr, localhost, port, telnet, remote-server

I have installed **Solr** on **remote server** and started on **port 8983**. Now, I have bind my **local machine port 8983** with **remote server 8983** of Solr using **ssh (Ubuntu OS)**. When I am **requesting** on **Solr** for getting the **suggestions** on remote server through local machine **calls**. Sometimes it gives **response**, sometimes **doesn't**.

I am not able to detect the problem that why is it so?
Is it remote server binding issue?  OR Solr went down ?
I am not getting the problem.

To detect the problem, I ran a **crontab** job using **telnet** command to **check existence of port (8983) of Solr**. It is **working fine** without throwing any connection refused error. I am **not** able to detect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but check the log section in the solr user interface.See what is says,secondly is your VM Ubuntu on a sepearte machine and database on a separate machine(remote database).This thing happened with me i use to get response very erratically.I later figured out that it was because my database vm was located someplace and vm on which solr was installed was located someplace.
Later we had the database on the same machine.

Comment: Okay. I can't put Solr on my local machine. It might be good if solr is placed on remote server. And also I can't put my local machine code on remote server.. Any idea rather than that.

Comment: when ever you dont get results just check the logs section in the solr UI dashboard(not the log file in the folder structure).Does it say something during that time.